# jQuery force enabled at first input which is not checked

Tags: jquery

I have separate divs inside a div with id=main. In each div i have different inputs.

Is there a way somehow to check in div with id=main all inputs and in each first input that is not disabled to check it?

Here is an example of HTML:

```
    <div id="main">
        <div class="inline-control-group">
           <input type="radio" value="7" id="cf4all1" class="cf4all_radio" name="name1" disabled="disabled">
        <label class="cf4all1" for="cf4all1">
        <div class="cf4all1inner" style="background-color:#ff2962; width:100%;">   
</div>
</label>
        </div>
        <div class="inline-control-group">
        <input type="radio" value="9" id="cf4all2" class="cf4all_radio" name="name2">
        <label class="cf4all2" for="cf4all2">
<div class="cf4all2inner" style="background-color:#000000; width:100%;"></div></label>
        </div>  
    </div>
```

At this example i have 2 divs inside main and inside each div i have an input. I need to check in main div, all inputs (each input of each div), check if its disabled, if yes check the other etc and for the first input that i find that is not disabled to check it (checked="checked"). In my example, the 2nd input that is not disabled should be checked.

Comment: Add your HTML please.

Comment: Please click the `<>` button and add a [mcve]

Comment: Just added a sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```js
$('#main').find('input:not([disabled="disabled"])').eq(0).attr('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div class="inline-control-group">
    <input type="radio" value="7" id="cf4all1" class="cf4all_radio" name="name1" disabled="disabled">
    <label class="cf4all1" for="cf4all1">
      <div class="cf4all1inner" style="background-color:#ff2962; width:100%;"></div></label>
  </div>
  <div class="inline-control-group">
    <input type="radio" value="9" id="cf4all2" class="cf4all_radio" name="name2">
    <label class="cf4all2" for="cf4all2">
      <div class="cf4all2inner" style="background-color:#000000; width:100%;"></div></label>
  </div>  
</div>
```

**Note:** Without `.eq(0)` it will check ***all inputs*** that are not disabled.

Comment: Ok i got your answer

Answer (score 0):

I think answer has already been given before I prepared the code for you hence would like to add it here since it is bit different too.

```
$('#main').find('input[type=radio]').not(':disabled')[0].checked = true;
```

**Solution:** [jsfiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/qo6re4aj)

Thanks,

Ashok